# Hibernate generates incorrect query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with composite key. **Subscription** and **Source** have Many-To-Many relationship.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "SUBSCRIPTION_SOURCES")
    data class SubscriptionSource (

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @MapsId("subs_id")
       val subscription: Subscription,

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @MapsId("source_id")
       val source: Source,

       @EmbeddedId
       val subscriptionSourceId: SubscriptionSourceId = SubscriptionSourceId(subscription.id, source.id),

       @Column(name = "value")
       val value : Long
   )

Table "SUBSCRIPTION_SOURCES" has only three columns: subs_id, source_id, value.
```

I'm using Spring Data repository to work with it.

When I'm trying to use method **saveAll**, it throws

> *"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'subscripti0_.subscription_id'"*

while trying to return value after saving.

Hibernate generates this query:

```
   select
        subscripti0_.source_id as source_i1_6_0_,
        subscripti0_.subs_id as subs_id2_6_0_,
        subscripti0_.subscription_id as subscrip4_6_0_, // error happens here
        subscripti0_.value as value3_6_0_ 
    from
        SUBSCRIPTION_SOURCES subscripti0_ 
    where
        subscripti0_.source_id=? 
        and subscripti0_.subs_id=?
```

So, now I am confused, why Hibernate is putting a string with **subscription_id** into the query, if I don't even have this field in my entities?

Class **SubscriptionSourceId**:

```
@Embeddable
data class SubscriptionSourceId (

    @Column(name = "subs_id")
    val subsId : Long?,

    @Column(name = "source_id")
    val sourceId : Long?

) : Serializable
```

class **Subscription**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBSCRIPTIONS")
data class Subscription(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        var id: Long? = null,

        @Column(name = "subscription_id")
        var subscriptionId: String?,

        @Column(name = "submitted_on")
        var submittedOn: LocalDateTime?,

        @Column(name = "status_MPP")
        var statusMpp: String?,

        @Column(name = "requested_by_user")
        var requestedByUser: String?,

        @Column(name = "requested_by_user_email")
        var requestedByUserEmail: String?,

        @Column(name = "organization_name")
        var organizationName: String?,

        @Column(name = "vm")
        var virtualMachine: String?,

        @Column(name = "node")
        var node: String?,

        @Column(name = "period")
        var period: String?,

        @Column(name = "ad_criterion")
        var adCriterion: String?,

        @Column(name = "name")
        var name: String?,

        @Column(name = "description")
        var description: String?,

        @Column(name = "s_number")
        var sNumber: String?,

        @Column(name = "p_number")
        var pNumber: String?,

        @Column(name = "reason")
        var reason: String?,

        @Column(name = "months")
        var months: String?,

        @Column(name = "start_date")
        var startDate: String?,

        @Column(name = "x_start_date")
        var actualStartDay: String? = startDate,

        @Column(name = "end_date")
        var endDate: String?,

        @Column(name = "x_end_date")
        var actualEndDate: String? = endDate,

        @Column(name = "channel")
        var channel: String?,

        @Column(name = "connection")
        var connection: String?,

        @Column(name = "connection_data")
        var connectionData: String?,

        @Column(name = "action")
        var action: String?,

        @Column(name = "department")
        var department: String?,

        @Column(name = "login")
        var login: String?,

        @Column(name = "customer_name")
        var customerName: String?,

        @Column(name = "customer_postaddress")
        var customerPostAddress: String?,

        @Column(name = "phone")
        var phone: String?,

        @Column(name = "customer_chief")
        var customerChief: String?,

        @Column(name = "user_name")
        var userName: String?,

        @Column(name = "position")
        var position: String?,

        @Column(name = "user_postaddress")
        var userPostAddress: String?,

        @Column(name = "user_phone")
        var userPhone: String?,

        @Column(name = "user_chief")
        var userChief: String?,

        @Column(name = "location")
        var location: String?,

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @Column(name = "status")
        var status: SubscriptionStatus? = SubscriptionStatus.REQUEST,

        @Column(name = "comment")
        var comment: String? = "",

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(
                name = "MTM_NODES2SUBSCRIPTIONS",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "subs_id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "node_id")]
        )
        var nodes : Set<Node> = emptySet(),

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "SUBSCRIPTION_SOURCES",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "subs_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "source_id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
        val sources : Set<Source?> = emptySet(),

        @Column(name = "db_status")
        val dbStatus: SubscriptionDbStatus?

)
```

Comment: can you post Subscription class?

Comment: either you forgot to use @id in the SubscriptionSourceId class or you did not specify the 'column name' for that parameter.

Comment: Do you really have attributes named subs_id and source_id in your SubscriptionSourceId class? That would violate the Java naming conventions. Post all the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've added code of Subscription and SubscriptionSourceId classes.

Comment: So you have no property named subs_id and source_id in SubscriptionSourceId. So `@MapsId("subs_id")` and `@MapsId("source_id")` aren't correct.

Comment: JB Nizet thank you for your answer. I tried to change property names to appropriate ones, it didn't work, then I tried to change value in annotation @MapsId, it also didn't work. Interesting thing, after my changes Hibernate changed its query. Second string with "subs_id" just disappeared. I still can't understand where problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved my problem. I've added @JoinColumn annotations to fields in **SubscriptionSource** class and changed value in @MapsId annotations as recommended by JB Nizet. Now it looks like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBSCRIPTION_SOURCES")
data class SubscriptionSource (

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("subsId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "subs_id")
    val subscription: Subscription,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("sourceId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_id")
    val source: Source,

    @EmbeddedId
    val subscriptionSourceId: SubscriptionSourceId = SubscriptionSourceId(subscription.id, source.id),

    @Column(name = "value")
    val value : Long
)
```

Thanks to all.